# Python h5py - 'Shape tuple is incompatible with data' error

Tags: python, tuples, h5py

I am trying to write a program which puts data into a .h5 file. There should be 3 columns, one with the number of the variable (from `counter` in the for loop. one with the name of the variable (shown in the 2nd column of `list_of_vars`), and one with its unit (3rd column of `list_of_vars`).

Code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py as h5

list_of_vars = [
    ('ADC_alt', 'ADC_alt', 'ft'),
    ('ADC_temp', 'ADC_temp', 'degC'),
    ('ADC_ias', 'ADC_ias', 'kts'),
    ('ADC_tas', 'ADC_tas', 'kts'),
    ('ADC_aos', 'ADC_aos', 'deg'),
    ('ADC_aoa', 'ADC_aoa', 'deg'),
]

#write new h5 file
var = h5.File('telemetry.h5','w')


for counter, val in enumerate(list_of_vars):
    varnum = var.create_dataset('n°', (6,), data = counter)
    varname = var.create_dataset('Variable name', (6,), dtype = 'str_', data = val[1])
    varunit = var.create_dataset('Unit', (6,), dtype = 'str_', data = val[2])
    data = np.array(varname,varunit)
print(data)
```

However, when I run it, I get the error `ValueError: Shape tuple is incompatible with data`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Lots of little problems to correct. If I understand, you want to create ONE heterogeneous dataset (with 1 field(column) of ints named `'n°'`, and 2 fields(columns) of strings named `'Variable name'` and `'Unit'`). What your code is trying to create is 18 separate datasets (3 created with each loop thru `enumerate(list_of_vars)`.

There is a trick when working with heterogeneous datasets: If you add row wise, you have to reference the dataset row AND column indices, OR add the entire row. I prefer to load data field/column wise. Generally you have fewer fields than rows -- fewer loops == fewer write cycles == faster.

Here is the process you want. It creates the dataset, then adds the data for each field from the count, then `list_of_vars[1]`, then from `list_of_vars[2]`. At the end it reads and prints the data from the dataset. Code below:

```
#write new h5 file
with h5.File('telemetry.h5','w') as var:

    dt = np.dtype( [('n°', int), ('Variable name','S10'), ('Unit', 'S10')] )      
    dset = var.create_dataset('data', dtype=dt, shape=(len(list_of_vars),))

    dset['n°'] = np.arange(len(list_of_vars))
    dset['Variable name'] = [val[1] for val in list_of_vars]
    dset['Unit'] = [val[2] for val in list_of_vars]

    data = dset[:]
    print(data)
```

If you prefer to use the `enumerate` loop, use this method. It loads items by row index. For completeness, it also shows how to index the dataset by `[row,field name]`, but do not recommend it.

```
#write new h5 file
with h5.File('telemetry.h5','w') as var:

    dt = np.dtype( [('n°', int), ('Variable name','S10'), ('Unit', 'S10')] )      
    dset = var.create_dataset('data',dtype=dt,shape=(len(list_of_vars),))

    for counter, val in enumerate(list_of_vars):
        dset[counter] = (counter, val[1], val[2])

        # alternate row/field indexing method:
        # dset[counter,'n°'] = counter
        # dset[counter,'Variable name'] = val[1]
        # dset[counter,'Unit'] = val[2]

    data = dset[:]
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

When asking about a problem, show the **whole** error.

When I run your code I get:

```
1129:~/mypy$ python3 stack68181330.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack68181330.py", line 18, in <module>
    varnum = var.create_dataset('n°', (6,), data = counter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 149, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(group, shape, dtype, data, name, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 61, in make_new_dset
    raise ValueError("Shape tuple is incompatible with data")
ValueError: Shape tuple is incompatible with data
```

It's having problems with your first dataset creation:

```
var.create_dataset('n°', (6,), data = counter)
```

What are you saying here?  Make a dataset with name 'n*', and shape (6,) - 6 elements.  But what is `counter`?  It's the current enumerate value, one **integer**.  Do you see how the shape (6,) doesn't match the `data`?

The other dataset lines potentially have similar problems.

It doesn't get on to another problem.  You are doing the `create_dataset` repeatedly in the loop.  Once you have a dataset named 'n*', you can't create another with the same name.

I suspect you want to make one dataset, with 6 slots, and repeatedly assign `counter` values to it.  Not to repeatedly create a dataset with the same name.

Let's change the dataset creation and write to something that works:

```
varnum = var.create_dataset('n°', (6,), dtype=int)
varname = var.create_dataset('Variable name', (6,), dtype = 'S10')
varunit = var.create_dataset('Unit', (6,), dtype = 'S10')
    
for counter, val in enumerate(list_of_vars):
    varnum[counter] = counter
    varname[counter] = val[1]
    varunit[counter] = val[2]
var.flush()
print(varnum, varnum[:])
print(varname) 
print(varname[:])
print(varunit)
print(varunit[:])
```

and run:

```
1144:~/mypy$ python3 stack68181330.py 
<HDF5 dataset "n°": shape (6,), type "<i8"> [0 1 2 3 4 5]
<HDF5 dataset "Variable name": shape (6,), type "|S10">
[b'ADC_alt' b'ADC_temp' b'ADC_ias' b'ADC_tas' b'ADC_aos' b'ADC_aoa']
<HDF5 dataset "Unit": shape (6,), type "|S10">
[b'ft' b'degC' b'kts' b'kts' b'deg' b'deg]
```

The `b'ft'` string display is bytestrings, the result of using `S10`.  I think there are ways of specifying unicode, but I haven't looked at the `h5py` docs in a while.

There are simpler ways of writing this data, but I chose to keep it close to your attempt, to better illustrate the basics of both Python iteration, and `h5py` use.

I could write the data directly to the datasets, without iteration with:

Make array from the list:

```
arr = np.array(list_of_vars, dtype='S')
print(arr)

varnum = var.create_dataset('n°', np.arange(arr.shape[0]))
varname = var.create_dataset('Variable name', data=arr[:,1])
varunit = var.create_dataset('Unit', data=arr[:,2])
```

I let it deduce shape and dtype from the `data`.